# Possible to export a database from PostgreSQL onto your computer hard drive

Tags: database, postgresql, save

Is it possible for me to export a database that i have created from PostgreSQL onto my hard drive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgdump.html) and it's various options on the command line to get it in a format you like.

Comment: If on windows, then yes, it can be the windows command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the database and click "Backup" using pgAdmin.